# SQL Query to identify accommodation booked

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, subquery, left-join

I need to know what SQL statement to use in an accommodation database looking for a trip user

Comment: images of text, such as your homework and the data, don't help us help you. Take the time to transcribe the text *yourself*. The error, however, is literally telling you the problem. To emphasise: **Column 'CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_NAME' is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.** Follow the directions the error implicitly gives you, and you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear enough: the `group by` clause needs to be consistent with the `select`. Some databases are smart enough to understand that the name of the customer is functionally dependent on its id, and do not require that you put the name in the `group by` - but not SQL Server.

Also, you need to count on something that comes from the `left join`ed table if you want `0` for customers without bookings.

Consider:

```
select c.customer_id, c.customer_name, count(ab.customer_id) as [number of accomm slots]
from customers c
left join  accommodation_bookings ab on c.customer_id = ab.customer_id
group by c.customer_id, c.customer_name
```

I would take one step forward and pre-aggregate in a subquery. This is usually more efficient:

```
select c.customer_id, c.customer_name, coalesce(ab.cnt, 0) [number of accomm slots]
from customers c
left join (
    select customer_id, count(*) cnt
    from accommodation_bookings 
    group by customer_id
) ab on c.customer_id = ab.customer_id
```

You could also express this with a correlated subquery, or a lateral join:

```
select c.customer_id, c.customer_name, ab.*
from customers c
outer apply (
    select count(*) [number of accomm slots]
    from accommodation_bookings ab
    where c.customer_id = ab.customer_id
) ab
```

This would take advantage of an index on `accommodation_bookings(customer_id)` (which should already be there if you have set up a foreign key).

Note: don't use single quotes for identifiers - they are meant for literal strings. In SQL Server, use the square brackets instead.